# Momentary switch arm and bypass circuit

Tags: switches

This is for an RPM limiting device when the clutch pedal is at the floor. The device is active only when it has either a ground or 12V input active (clutch at floor situation). I would like a circuit that would allow this input to be allowed after an "arm" button has been pressed.

```
                __________________
Clutch down ___|                  |____________
                   ___
Arm button  ______|   |________________________
                   _______________
Output      ______|               |____________
                                     __________
Clutch up   ________________________|          
                                     ___________
Reset       ________________________|
```

*Figure 1. Timing diagram added by @Transistor for OP to edit.*

Comment: Welcome to EE stackexchange.  Your requirements are bit unclear.  Can you perhaps reword the question with a better explanation of what's being controlled, signals available and how they pertain, etc.?

Comment: Thank you. I have a device that requires an input of either a ground or +12VDC to become active. This input needs to be activated by a momentary switch (which I will physically hold down), then after I release the switch, it not trigger the device input (even if I press the momentary switch) until I press an "arm" or reset button.

Comment: <!-- Begin schematic: In order to preserve an editable schematic, please
     don't edit this section directly.
     Click the "edit" link below the image in the preview instead. -->

![schematic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gpt12.png)

<!-- End schematic -->

Comment: SW1 would be the "arm", SW2 is the 12V input to the device. So, press and hold SW1, then press and hold SW2. Release SW1, when task is complete, SW2 will be released. After that if SW1 is pressed, there will be no 12V input to the device.

Comment: I've added a timing diagram for you which, when edited, will be much better than a pile of words. Note that I have taken you literally with the "after an arm button has been pressed". In my timing diagram the arm button doesn't have to be held. Also note that you have not specified how the circuit is to reset - so it doesn't.

Comment: I can't get a timing diagram to look nice on here to save my life. What you have is close. The clutch stays down the whole time you want the output. Once the clutch is up, the arm button needs to be pressed to get the output, even if you press the clutch down again.

Comment: (1) If `clutch up = NOT down`then you can remove your clutch up line as that condition is covered by the first line. (2) Your modified timing diagram shows that the output turns off when the clutch pedal is released. Is this correct? (3) If you *do* need the clutch up line then you're going to need another switch and another input. Please clarify. (4) When did RESET appear? It's not mentioned in the question. Make the question good. Don't sprinkle the info through the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                __________________
Clutch down ___|                  |____________
                   ___
Arm button  ______|   |________________________
                   _______________
Output      ______|               |____________
```

*Figure 1. From the question, the modified timing diagram and the comments I think the above is what is required.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDCkn5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Two options.*

Figure 2 top uses a contact of RLY1 to hold the power on after ARM has been released.

Figure 2 bottom also uses RLY2 to hold the power on but uses the relay to switch the output. This would be an advantage if the downstream device is a high current load.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f39g2c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you use this signal as an input to a micro controller or a logic IC, you may want to use a pull down resistor and a appropriate voltage divider before connecting the 12V signal directly to the input.

Comment: I edited the timing diagram. Will the input still get 12V after the arm button is released? SW2 is held down until input is no longer needed.

Comment: @TChap Yes. when the ARM is pressed the relay is energized and since the SW2 is already on, even after releasing ARM, the SW2 will provide 12V for the relay coil through the diode. Once the SW2 is released, the relay is cut off and the output will be disconnected from 12V.

Comment: I see it now! Thank you VERY much. Way more simple than the Rube Goldberg way I had it.